# Issue in Spring MVC serving static resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am running the Spring application with JQuery. But the application is not running. After the JQuery function is called the application is not working. For example please refer the below image, the `alert('name')` after the `$('#name').val();` is not working.
Can any one please tell why it is not working?

I have added the JQuery file in js folder in WebContent.

And for importing the jquery i used the

```
<script src="/AjaxWithSpringMVC2Annotation/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

in JSP page.

Here's the full JSP source:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Users using ajax</title>
<script src="/AjaxWithSpringMVC2Annotation/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doAjaxPost() {
        // get the form values
        alert('doAjaxPost ');
        var name = $('#name').val();
        alert('name ');
        var education = $('#education').val();
        alert('education ');

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/AjaxWithSpringMVC2Annotation/AddUser.htm",
            data : "name=" + name + "&education=" + education,
            success : function(response) {
                // we have the response
                $('#info').html(response);
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#education').val('');
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Users using Ajax ........</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your name :</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="name"><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Education :</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="education"><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add Users"
                onclick="doAjaxPost()"><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div id="info" style="color: green;"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="/AjaxWithSpringMVC2Annotation/showUsers.htm">Show All
        Users</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say `alert('name ');` isn't working, but does the `alert('education ');` call work? Does your AJAX request occur? Are there errors in your developer console? Does `name` have a value after `$('name').val()`, or is it there an error on that line?

Comment: no error in console, no ajax request or alert('education') is working. Whenever the jquery method is called the application is not working. After this jquery method  $('name').val() nothing is working. I think jquery is not loaded properly. I am using this script to load the jquery.<script src="/AjaxWithSpringMVC2Annotation/js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: Try going to `<your domain>/AjaxWithSpringMVC2Annotation/js/jquery.js` in your browser to see if it is getting the jQuery script or not. It is working if you see the text contents of the script file in your browser viewport.

Comment: it was redirecting to index page. I am not seeing the text content.

Comment: That's... interesting. So presumably the fact that your index page is returned when the jQuery script file is requested means that you won't actually get your jQuery script file loaded, which would cause any JavaScript code trying to use jQuery to fail. I'm surprised you're not getting something like a `'$' not defined` error.

Comment: I am not getting the error '$' not defined. But it was working in the tutorial example i am studying.

Comment: Likely because they had their jQuery script loading correctly, whereas it appears that yours is not. Perhaps try making a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) out of it. You'll have to include jQuery from the left-side menu, and make your AJAX a stub (since JSFiddle obviously won't be supporting the back-end stuff you have, and that's not what's wrong here anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a resource handler for the path *js/***. See [17.15.6 Configuring Serving of Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
    }

}
```

or in XML:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>
```

Comment: I added the class but it is not working. Do i need to create the object for this class? Or Spring will take care?

Comment: This class is part of your application context. If you don't use Java config you have to do it the XML way (I think it's <mvc:resources />). See [17.15.6 Configuring Serving of Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources).

Comment: I tried the below but it is not working. I have the js folder under the WebContent folder. Do i need to change the path here.  <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/" />

Comment: Yes, add a <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>.

Comment: Thanks for your help but still it is not working, i am reading this example from one tutorial i tried the example it is running with out adding the mvc resource.